# Why is my ActiveRecord order method denying knowledge of a derived column from a select method?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have written an ActiveRecord query designed to order my invoices by the sum of a column in an associated table (Invoice has_many :item_numbers). It involves some complex (for me) class methods but it ends up like this;

```
Invoice.where(user_id: 1, deleted: false, status: 'Sent').joins(:item_numbers).select('invoices.*, sum(item_numbers.amount) as total').group('invoices.id').order('total asc').limit(20)
```

If I run this query in the console I get the expected result - my first twenty invoices ordered by the total of their item_numbers. When it runs in the development server though, I get the following error from Postgresql;

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "total" does not exist
```

As the query that is run on the server depends on a lot of scopes and class methods, to check that the query is correct, I called `.to_sql` on it and the output in the browser was;

```
SELECT  invoices.*, sum(item_numbers.amount_with_gst) as total FROM "invoices" INNER JOIN "item_numbers" ON "item_numbers"."invoice_id" = "invoices"."id" WHERE "invoices"."user_id" = 1 AND "invoices"."deleted" = 'f' AND "invoices"."status" = 'Sent' GROUP BY invoices.id ORDER BY total asc LIMIT 20
```

I get exactly the same output if I call `.to_sql` on the query itself in the console, and if I put this output into `Invoice.find_by_sql` in the console I don't get the error.

This feels like some sort of weird bug, but I know that the bug is most likely mine. I have hunted for a few hours now with no clues - can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a problem with ActiveRecord. As you demonstrated, ActiveRecord has no problem with your code and it happily creates a SQL statement. But one which PostgreSQL doesn´t like: The `PG::Error` exception is a low level exception coming from the database adapter stating that your SQL query is not valid.

PostgreSQL simply doesn't support **expression aliases** in the `ORDER BY` statement. (Have a look at the [documentation for `ORDER BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY))

You have to repeat the expression in the order statement:

```
Invoice.select('invoices.*, sum(item_numbers.amount) as total')
  .order('sum(item_numbers.amount) asc')
```

Don't worry, the query optimizer will detect that and your sum is still calculated just once.

Most likely you are using a different DBMS on your console and your development server. (MySQL or SQLite?) Some database engines accept expression aliases, some don't.

Comment: hmm...your solution worked for me but what's strange is that the query worked when I tried it directly in postgres using the pgadmin client.  I.e. the alias expression in the ORDER BY statement